# TypeError when calculating fields where all fields are Float

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, typeerror

In ArcGIS Pro (2.9), I have a polygon vector layer with census data. I want to use Calculate Field to create a diversity index using the values of eight fields but I keep getting TypeErrors:

> ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<
> expression>", line 1, in  TypeError: unsupported operand
> type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

These eight fields I am using in my calculation are percentages of the total population for each demographic group called per_white, per_black, per_ameri_es, per_asian, per_hawnpi, per_other, per_hisp, and per_Nhisp. All of these 8 fields were created by me and given Data Type float and Numeric Format with 6 decimals. Then I used a simple calculation to populate the data in each field (e.g., the population of WHITE people in a census tract / total population in census tract = "per_white".

Here is the calculation to calculate a diversity index of the demographic data that results in the TypeError:

```
div_ind =
1 - ([!per_white!]^2 + [!per_black!]^2 + [!per_amer_es!]^2 + [!per_asian!]^2 + [!per_hawnpi!]^2 + [!per_other!]^2) * ([!per_hisp!]^2 + [!per_Nhisp!]^2)
```

I don't know Python so I'm just using the field calculator. Why am I getting the type error if all my fields used in the calculation, as well as the target Field (div_index), are formatted as float?

Comment: Sorry. this is from the top of my head. I cannot test it now. In python, something between square brackets is a list. Try to remove the square brackets in your expression. I think squared is `**2` and not `^2`
`div_ind =
1 - (!per_white!**2 + !per_black!**2 + !per_amer_es!**2 + !per_asian!**2 + !per_hawnpi!**2 + !per_other!**2) * (!per_hisp!**2 + !per_Nhisp!**2)`

Comment: @ChloeG Exactly. `**` is exponentiation, `^` is a bitwise `XOR` operation. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp.

Comment: Thank you @Berend I didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This worked. I'm impressed with the speed and accuracy of the answer. The generosity of people like you makes GIS worthwhile!

Comment: I am glad it was useful. I will write it as a proper answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

What the error message says is that you tried to make a calculation with an integer and a list.

In python, a list is created by using square brackets. Even if your field `!per_white!` is a number, `[!per_white!]` is a list containing one element. Removing the square brackets should solve the issue.

To square a number in python, you need to use `**2`.

With these changes, your expression should now be:

`div_ind = 1 - (!per_white!**2 + !per_black!**2 + !per_amer_es!**2 + !per_asian!**2 + !per_hawnpi!**2 + !per_other!**2) * (!per_hisp!**2 + !per_Nhisp!**2)`